# How much, what order and where to put data?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I've been updating and moving my massage business website to Wordpress. During SEO process I interested and decided to include some structured data but I'm bit confused how to do it properly. I'm going to test that stuff first on my current site.

I'm going to present information with JSON-LD and I've been reading alot of schema-org manuals and blog posts about the schemas, still they are bit vaque to me.

1. How much data should I provide?

- I still would like to present list of services we provide and price range by currency/min/maxPrice and persons data who are working there (name, profession, phone).

2. Would it be wise to put that data in the `<head>`-section of every page?

- Or just specific data to page that they relate to like staff info to "Contact Us" page and service list to "Services" page?
- Is there any penalty or down sides to have all that data on every page?

3. How do I present personal courses that every person has taken or other studies?
4. How do I present those services?
5. Can business under that `HealthAndBeautyBusiness` handle 3 phone numbers with names or should I just put contact info under person's data?
6. Does it matter in which order I present that data?

Comment: These are too many questions that aren’t closely related. You should make your question post about one specific question (and possibly related sub-questions).

Answer (score 0):

1. The more data you provide, the better
2. Better to be specific, otherwise it *could* be interpreted as spam. The structured data should be closely related to the content of the page itself
3. You mean the employees? You could use the `employee` property and the `alumniOf` properties but that doesn't match it very well. I think such data is a bit too detailed to be described at the moment - I would omit it for the time being
4. List them as offers, see `makesOffer` property
5. I would limit it to 1 number
6. The order doesn't matter

In the future try to split your questions, would be much easier to answer them that way.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm going to present information with JSON-LD and I've been reading alot of schema-org manuals and blog posts about the schemas, still they are bit vaque to me.

In regards to this statement.  If I were you, and I'm not, therefore I can only assume you are just learning about technologies such as [json-ld](/questions/tagged/json-ld) and how they relate to the bigger picture that is the **Semantic Web** also known as Web 3.0.

It sounds like you are on the right track I would suggest additionally reading articles relating to [api](/questions/tagged/api)'s as well as the [http](/questions/tagged/http) request life cycle. 
-Happy Coding